# A Zip utility that works with Zip archives appended to other files (e.g. sfx archives)

Tags: zip

I have a file that is a DLL with an appended Zip archive (using simple concatenation, i.e. `cat a.dll b.zip > c.xyz`). I can append files to this archive with a Python script that uses the standard `zipfile` module, but when I try to use it with other tools (7-Zip, WinZip, command-line `zip` and `unzip` from Cygwin) they either cannot open the archive at all (WinZip) or can only read it, but cannot append new files.

- Is this related to the fact that the archive is simply concatenated to a file? Maybe there's a more compatible way to do this?
- Is there a Zip utility with a graphical user interface on Windows and/or Mac OS X that can correctly append files to such an archive? (Ideally, also delete or update files).

Comment: Are you able to open other dll files or files of another format?

Comment: @Kivitoe I don't understand; yes, I can open standard archives and add files to them, e.g. with 7-Zip. But with this archive it errs with "Not implemented" error. I cannot open standard DLLs because they don't have a Zip file attached to them.

Comment: It could be corrupted, that's all I've got.